# Django how to use |yesno to to toggle views

Tags: html, django, toggle

I need to create a toggle inside of my html that allows me to switch between data in two separate models. Below is the line of code in my html I've used to try and do this:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="{{ url }}{{ seller|yesno:"?seller=true,?seller=false,?seller=test"}}" >
```

View:

```
seller = False

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.GET.get('seller', None) == '?seller=true':
            self.model = CarSeller
            self.seller = True
        elif self.request.GET.get('seller', None) == '?seller=false':
            self.model = VanSeller
            self.seller = False

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.model == CarSeller:
            com = self.model.objects.filter(
                carparty=self.vehicle.proff.car_contact.garage,
            )
        else:
            com = self.model.objects.filter(
                vanparty=self.vehicle.proff.van_contact,
            )
        return communication

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context['seller'] = self.seller
        context['url'] = reverse_lazy(
            "work:contact:comm_intro",
            kwargs={'vehicle_id': self.vehicle.id}
        )

        return context
```

To my understanding of reading about use of yesno this should work but instead once i click the button it will swap to true but the value does not change back to false when i press it again. All help appreciated on use of |yesno or any recommendations on how you think i should display this. Any variable you may see missing to do with models and unrelated to question is probably because I've skimmed it out for question.

Thanks

(Anything else needed let me know)

Comment: You could debug this problem by printing/logging values in your code. If you added `print(request.GET.get('seller', None)`, you would see what the problem is in your code.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `reverse_lazy` inside the `get_context_data` method. The regular `lazy` method will work fine.

Comment: @Alasdair the button doesn't seem to change value if i reload the page from previous page and click button it does not work at all just print's False

Comment: I'm not sure I would use `yesno` here. You might find `{{ url }}?seller={% if seller %}true{% else %}false{% false %}` more readable. Or you could set `context['seller']` to `'true'` or `'false'` in `get_context_data`, then all you need is `{{ url }}?seller={{ seller }}`

Comment: @Alasdair    I've tried your first suggestion and i'm attempting to debug but i don't quite see anything wrong that is causing this issue even with suggestion of not using yesno my button still won't toggle it just sticks on False, not sure what you mean with do it all in context i wouldn't know how to structure that one.

Comment: "it just sticks on False" is not enough info to debug. What is the rendered url in the template? When you click on that, what are the values of `self.request.GET`, `self.request.GET('seller')` and `self.seller` in your `get` method? Are they what you expect? If so, what is `context` in `get_context_url`? Is `context['seller']` what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The value of seller will be `'true'`, `'false'` (or `test` for `None`). You should remove the `?seller=` from the string in your comparison, e.g.

```
self.request.GET.get('seller', None) == 'true'
```

Since `None` is the default for `get()`, you can simplify further to

```
self.request.GET.get('seller') == 'true'
```

Comment: I have amended this although the outcome is still the same my button switchs on first click then for every interaction after it does not change bool value

Comment: This kind of problem is easier for you to debug, since you can run the code. Your `get_context_data` looks incorrect since you don't define `context` anywhere. You need to systematically work through the view and the template, and make sure the values are what you expect in each place.